# Cron Register everytime if i reload admin if i pass some extra argument in wp_schedule_event function

Tags: functions, wp-cron, cron

Cron Register everytime if i reload admin if i pass some extra argument in wp_schedule_event function.

Here you can check the scrrenshot

[image]

I have checked the cron using the plugin WP Control.

```
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_one_hoursinwp'] = array(
       'interval' => 3600,
       'display'  => __( 'Every 1 hours in WP' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_one_hoursinwp', 'myprefix_cron_hook',array(42));
}

add_action( 'myprefix_cron_hook', 'myprefix_cron_function');

function myprefix_cron_function($args) {
    update_option('helo_'.time(),$args);
}
```

If i removed the array(42) value as fourth argument it works fine.

Can any one point out the issue why it added multiple times when i pass an argument.

Comment: Please check this example : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_next_scheduled/#user-contributed-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because this code:

```php
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_one_hoursinwp', 'myprefix_cron_hook',array(42));
}
```

Is the same as this code:

```php
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook', array() ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_one_hoursinwp', 'myprefix_cron_hook',array(42));
}
```

And while you have lots of cron jobs with `array(42)`, there is no next scheduled cron job with no arguments, so the `if` statement is true.

To fix this, use the second parameter of `wp_next_scheduled`:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_next_scheduled/

Think of it this way, if you had multiple cron jobs with different arguments, how would you check which ones have been scheduled if you couldn't pass the arguments?